# Java substring to split up name

Tags: java, substring

I am asked to take input from a user, their first and last name in one string.

Then output their name, with their last name first then their first name.

I have finished everything but the part I am stuck on is how to show their first name then their last name, please help.

This is my code so far as requested

```
package chapter2Codes;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StPrac1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String name;

        System.out.println("Please your full name");

        Scanner kbd = new Scanner( System.in );
        name = kbd.nextLine();

        System.out.print(name.substring(5,8) + (", ") + name.substring(0,));


    }
}
```

Comment: Your question is pretty vague. Please show what you have tried and someone will help you correct it.

Comment: @sethZiotic How you want to display if you have middle name as well

Comment: @DCODE it only asks for first and last name, no middle name

Comment: @SethZiotic then try the code as below (and you have to apply your filters as well, cause you never know what enduser gonna enter)

Comment: @DCODE i don't think u are understanding the question, let me rephrase it.

Comment: @DCODE "Write a program which asks user for their name (first and last as one string input), After receiving input format the name entered by the user so that it outputs a string where the last name is placed first, followed by a comma and a space, and then the first name"

Comment: @SethZiotic pls check my updated post, variable 'output' will give what u want

Comment: @DCODE thxx!!! it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Firstname and Lastname are seperated by white-space then try this

```
    var fullname = "Firstname Surname";
    var fname = fullname.Split(" ")[0];
    var sname = fullname.Split(" ")[1];
    string output = sname + ", " + fname;
```

OR if you want to Avoid middle name

```
 string fullName = "Firstname MidName LastName"; 
 string[] names = fullName.Split(' '); 
 string fname = names.First();
 string lname = names.Last(); 
 string output = lname + ", " + fname;
```

OR use your delimeter in .Split('addyourdelimeterhere')

AS per your Code

```
public class StPrac1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String name;

        System.out.println("Please your full name");

        Scanner kbd = new Scanner( System.in );
        name = kbd.nextLine();
        string fname = name.Split(" ")[0];
        string sname = name.Split(" ")[1];
        string output = sname + ", " + fname;

        System.out.print(output);


    }
    }
```

This is just an example not a perfect solution, It will be easy to help you if you can Post more detail